# Is it possible to query google maps for multiple store names?

Tags: google-maps, url, kml

I have a store locator that until now only needed to look for one specific business name. So when a user would find a store near them, it would just use their current position and query for all the stores near them. However, now I need to include multiple different store types. So for instance, if I wanted to deep link to the maps app/site and search for both target and walmart, is that possible? Could this be done by passing a KML maybe?

Edit: To be a little more clear, I am not implementing my own map on my site. It is linking to google maps with a payload for the search. So it either deep links on mobile to the google maps app or the site on desktop. I am wondering if it is possible to construct a query for the URL to be able to display more than a single store on the map.

So for instance we have:

```
window.open("https://maps.google.com?near=&q=" + query,'_blank');
```

Where query would be the store name. However, simply using logic operators won't return two stores in the map. It will try to treat one of them as a street name or something to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple queries, store them, and then show them with their corresponding markers.

Comment: I revised my original question, I should have been more specific. We aren't implementing our own map.